# Add a "Like" button to a native comments entries tag?

Tags: comments

Like some of the social comment engines, is there an add-on to allow users to "like" a comment within an entry (and not the entry itself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Flag Master](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/flag-master); it's built specifically to allow you do exactly that (and a whole lot more). You can setup your own "sets" of options (or just 1) and is completely AJAX compatible and made with love.

Comment: Hi Eric,

So Flag Master allows me to "flag" any content user chooses, including individual comments in the native EE comment system?


Of course, as long as the user is logged in, each "flag" will remain personal for that user?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. The only difference is Flag Master can also work with logged out users if you like (it's configurable). Take a look at this page: http://mithra62.com/docs/detail/export-it-installation

Both the article (entry) and comments have Flag Master used on them. The entry uses multiple options to create a poll of sorts while the comments have a single "Inappropriate" button (similar to your "Like" option).

Comment: Awesome - I'll speak with the client to get this approved for purchase. Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 1):

Likee is free and on my shortlist to try out.
http://booyant.com/likee

Comment: Thanks very much -- so far I[m leaning towards Eric's Flagmaster, but I've downloaded likee as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Although not using the native EE comment module, if you use Solspace's [Rating](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/) module instead, you can use the **review** field in a Rating form as an entry comment. This can be done without using the **rating** field. Then, users can rate a rating/review *up* or *down* using the [{exp:rating:insert_rating_vote}](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/insert_rating_vote/) tag. This could be used as an equivalent of "liking" (or "disliking") a comment.

Comment: Thanks -- as you probably know already I'm a big proponent of the Rating module. I didn't know that it could be used that way. Terrific idea.

Answer (score 0):

Might be not exactly what you're looking for, but you can use [Bookmarks](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bookmarks) to let users bookmark comments.

Though different, the concept is still similar to likes.

Use can use `{exp:bookmarks:by type='comment' data_id='{comment_id}'}{total_results}{/exp:bookmarks:by}` to display total number of bookmarks for the comment and `{exp:bookmarks:check}` to display 'add-to-bookmarks' form

Comment: Thanks Yuri! Although I think Flag Master would be more appropriate to what I've got going, but I'm looking to use Bookmarks on another project.

Answer (score 0):

If one were so inclined, you could take Low's http://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/how-to-develop-expressionengine-add-on/ which does 'likes' for an entry and modify it to do likes for a comment entry.

Comment: Dammit Steven! We don't want people *learning* how to do this on their own :p

Comment: Shut up, Eric! Let Steven speak! ;)

Comment: LOL - I've got no plans to build an add-on. I'd be happy to always budget for a commercial one to support the awesome developer community!